# How to sum the total of same group and same month?

Tags: sql

I have a view which is in the following format:

```
channel | theMonth | theCount |
-------------------------------
chaA    |        3 |        5 |
-------------------------------
chaA    |        2 |        2 |
-------------------------------
chaA    |        1 |        4 |
-------------------------------
chaB    |        2 |        1 |
-------------------------------
```

I would like to **SUM theCount which having the same month as current month (assuming current month is March) with the previous month**, thus chaA (channel) of 3 (theMonth) will have theCount value of 7 (5+2). The expected output will shown like this:

```
channel | theMonth | theCount |
-------------------------------
chaA    |        3 |        7 |  --> Note: this row has been updated.
-------------------------------
chaA    |        2 |        2 |  --> Retain the value
-------------------------------
chaA    |        1 |        4 |  --> Retain the value
-------------------------------
chaB    |        2 |        1 |  --> Retain the value
-------------------------------
```

I have been using SQL case to fix this solution, like following code, but failed:

```
select channel, theMonth, 
case when month(date('2012-03-31')) = theMonth and 
     month(date('2012-03-31')) - 1 = theMonth
         then sum(theCount) 
else sum(theCount) end as theCount
from theView
```

Is there any alternate solution beside using SQL case? Please not limit to any database technology as this is a general SQL query.

Comment: How do you arrive at 7 = 5 + 2? In your original view I only see a 5 for theCount in month 3, it is unclear where you pull that 2 from.

Comment: Also, what exactly do you want to achieve? group and sum only over month 3 but leave all other months as is (showing up unaggregated as they are in the original view)?

Comment: I need to sum theCount of current month and previous month together, the current month is dynamic variable, most probably will use "today" in the SQL to query today's date. Assuming current month is March, which is value 3 in theMonth, thus previous month is Feb, which is value 2 in theMonth. By extracting the value of 5 and 2 from theCount column, you will get 7 in total and then update it back to the current month, which is value of 3 in theMonth.

Comment: did any of the answers solve your problem? Let us know...

Answer (score 3):

if your database supports analytic function `lag` (Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL, Terradata, ?) and no months are missing (i.e. theCount = 0 instead of missing row):

```
select channel, theMonth,
  case
    when theMonth = 3
    then theCount + lag(theCount) over (partition by channel order by theMonth)
    else theCount
  end as theCount
from theView
```

Comment: Add PostgreSQL and Terradata to the list of DBMS supporting `lag`

Comment: I just try it in Informix and found out that it is not working. Does your code support Informix?

Comment: @huahsin68 You wrote "don't limit to any database technology" - this could be construed to mean we should not hold back any solutions even though it may not be available in some RDBMS-es. You probably meant the opposite. If that's the case be more clear in the future: "I want a solution that works across as many RDBMS-es as possible"

Answer (score 2):

You can use UNION

```
select channel, theMonth, sum(theCount)
from 
(
    (
    select channel, MONTH(TODAY()) as theMonth, sum(theCount)
    from sourceTable
    where theMonth =  MONTH(TODAY()) or theMonth = MONTH(TODAY())-1
    and exists (select theMonth from sourceTable where theMonth=MONTH(TODAY()))
    )
    union
    (
    select channel, theMonth, sum(theCount)
    where theMonth<MONTH(TODAY())
    )
)
```

This can work, it also checks if rows with the actual month exist

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, the requirement is to report the counts for each month, except for the current month: that should be summed with the count of the previous month.

I would go for a simple auto-join in that case:

```
select     curr.month
,          curr.count + coalesce(prev.count, 0)
from       v as curr
left join  v as prev
on         curr.month = month(today())  -- only join if the month is the current month
and        curr.month - 1 = prev.month  -- join with the previous month
```

I suspec that with the concrete example, we also need to take the channel into account so the total query would become:

```
select     curr.channel
,          curr.month
,          curr.count + coalesce(prev.count, 0)
from       v as curr
left join  v as prev
on         curr.month     = month(today())  -- only join if the month is the current month
and        curr.month - 1 = prev.month      -- join with the previous month
and        curr.channel   = prev.channel
```

Comment: In my code, the month() and today() functions are made up - they are placeholders for the hopefully clear semantics. There are site such as you require, but you can google as well as I can.